# テキストに対して正規表現を含む複数の検索置換をバッチでかけたい

Tags: macos, 正規表現

環境はMac OS X 10.9です。
エディタで検索置換するか、コンソールでするかなどは問いません。
テキストは上書きされてもされなくても構いません。

> 例、以下のようなテキストを複数の検索置換ワードにバッチでかけて処理したい
>   `<p>aaaaa</p>`
>    ↓
>   `<p class="hoge">bbbbb</p>`
>
> 検索ワード：aaaaa　置換ワード：bbbbb
>   検索ワード：`^<p>`　置換ワード:`<p class="hoge">`

今のところ、CotEditor付属のrubyスクリプトが簡単にできたのですが、
環境が異なると動作しなくなるなど少し不安定のようで、
もっとシンプルな方法がないかを知りたく質問いたしました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` を使うなどどうでしょうか。
ターミナルから次を実行します。

```
sed -i .bk -e 's/aaaaa/bbbbb/g' -e 's/^<p>/<p class="hoge">/g' TARGET_FILE
```

このコマンドは、対象ファイルに上書きします。またその際元ファイルのバックアップ(`TARGET.bk`)を作成します。
バックアップファイルが不要の場合は、

```
sed -i .bk -e 's/aaaaa/bbbbb/g' -e 's/^<p>/<p class="hoge">/g' TARGET_FILE && rm TARGET_FILE.bk
```

などするとよいです。

Comment: BSD 系の sed コマンドでバックアップが不要な場合は `sed -i '' -e ...` とすると良いですよ(GNU sed であれば `sed -i -e ...` でも可)。

Comment: @argus  sed の `-i` の説明(Man-page)に、 `It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.` と書いてあったので、このような回答にしたのですが、取り越し苦労、なのかもしれませんね。。

Comment: sedですと例えば半角スラッシュを検索ワードに入れたいのに区切り文字として認識されてしまうとかちょっと大変そうだったので避けておりました…
調べるとコロンなどでも代用できるようですので、もう少し頑張ってみます。ありがとうございました

Answer (score 1):

二つに分けずとも、検索ワード：`^<p>aaaaa<\/p>` 置換ワード：`<p class="hoge">bbbbb<\/p>`で行けると思いますが、行頭を示す`^`を除いて正規表現の必要もほとんどないと思いますが、求めている回答とは主旨が違いますか？